# How can I replaced SharePoint 2013 survey question text with image?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, survey

How can I replaced SharePoint 2013 survey question text with image? I cant get the ms-formlabel class in my javascrip.

Below is the script I am Using:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var className;
className = 'ms-formlabel';ms-formlabel

var elements = new Array();
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var e = 0; e < elements.length; e++)
{
    if (elements[e].className == className)
    {
        elements[e].innerHTML = elements[e].innerHTML.replace('jj','<img src="/PublishingImages/icon-document.png"></img>');
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for you. I have created a survey list which has questions as below format

Image1

- Enter Choice #1
- Enter Choice #2
- Enter Choice #3

Image2

- Enter Choice #1
- Enter Choice #2
- Enter Choice #3

I used the text of the question as the token to find the right placeholder for the image and appended the image there using the below script.

```
function SetImage(){
var image1="<img src='/PublishingImages/icon-document.png'></img>"
var image1Question = $("table.ms-formtable .ms-formlabel:contains('jjj')");
$(image1Question).html("");
$(image1).appendTo(image1Question);
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    SetImage();
});
```

It works fine for me. Cheers.

Comment: Is it working in Sharepoint 2013 too? Because I cant get the class i.e. ms-formlabel.

Comment: this gives me undefined for .html()

Comment: The code i have shared is also tested in SP2013. Can you share the html format of the table where you are trying to find the class.

Comment: <table class="ms-formtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 8px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="90%" valign="top"> jjj </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formbody" width="90%" valign="top">
<span dir="none">

</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: here, I can get object with class but i can't get inner html. It gives me undefined. so I can not replace text inside it.

Comment: Try the above code now. I have replaced the 'Image1' token with 'jjj' as per your html. Check out.

Comment: Thankyou so much. it's working now. Previously it was not working because of document.ready not written.